# How do I set property for one, and remove the rest?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the width and left to the corresponding element, and when another button is clicked, switch the earlier button property back to   --left: 50%; --width: 0;. So that only the button that was most recently clicked, has the 70% and 17.5% width and left. I am doing it this way, because I am changing :after properties.

```js
const navButton = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-button');
const navListInside = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-list-inside');

for (let i = 0; i < navButton.length; i++) {
  navButton[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    scroll(i);
    navListInside[i].style.setProperty('--width', '70%');
    navListInside[i].style.setProperty('--left', '17.5%');
  });
}
```

```css
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#list-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 75px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 10px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.nav-list-inside {
  --left: 50%;
  --width: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  /* padding: 0 10px; */
  /* margin: 0 30px; */
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-list-inside:after {
  content: "";
  width: var(--width);
  height: 3px;
  background: var(--neon-blue);
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--left);
  bottom: -10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <ul id="list-nav">
    <li class="nav-list-inside"><button class="nav-button">Name</button></li>
    <li class="nav-list-inside"><button class="nav-button">Home</button></li>
    <li class="nav-list-inside"><button class="nav-button">Services</button></li>
    <li class="nav-list-inside"><button class="nav-button">About us</button></li>
    <li class="nav-list-inside"><button class="nav-button">Contact us</button></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant "*[mcve]*" HTML - and CSS - so that we can accurately reproduce your problem, and provide verified answers.

Comment: @DavidThomas all done!

Comment: I've converted the code into a working snippet; but you've got `white` text on a `white` background; would you care to edit the CSS and specify a contrasting colour where you feel it's appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you use the same variable `i` in all of your event listener functions, so `i` always has the same value. To avoid this, replace the `for` loop with a [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) call.

Also, after setting the new properties for the clicked button, you must reset them for all other buttons.

```js
navButton.forEach(function(button, i) {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    scroll(i);
    navListInside[i].style.setProperty('--width', '70%');
    navListInside[i].style.setProperty('--left', '17.5%');
    for (let j = 0; j < navButton.length; j++) if (j !== i) {
      navListInside[j].style.setProperty('--width', '0');
      navListInside[j].style.setProperty('--left', '50%');
  });
});
```

Instead of manipulating the properties directly, you can also introduce a `.pressed` class as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: When I do it this way, the --width and --left don't stay in place for the element and go back to 0 and 50% for all. Without the for loop, the clicked button styles stay, but don't go away, as I experienced myself. It's a bit trickier, at least for me, because I am editing pseudo elements.

Comment: Sorry, typo in my answer (`i` becomes `j`), have corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

Add classes with each property you want and take away and add that class to each button as pressed. Heres an example:

CSS:

```
.pressed{
    width: 70%;
    left: 17.5%;
}
```

JS:

```
for(let i = 0; i < navButton.length; i++){
  navButton[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    scroll(i);
    for(let i = 0; i < navButton.length; i++){
        navListInside[i].removeClass("pressed");
    }
    navListInside[i].addClass("pressed");
    });
  }
};
```

For HTML, you just have to add pressed to whichever one is the starting one.

Answer (score 0):

on your click event listener, on every click you should clear previous style of all buttons and then, set 'left' and 'width' style on the button which is clicked. Here I just did it for 'left' property:

```
navButton[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    navListInside.forEach((btn) => btn.style.setProperty('left', '0px')) // switch the earlier buttons property back
    navListInside[i].style.setProperty('left', '20px'); // '--left' shuold also change to 'left'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation and inside of that listener use for loop to set back `left` to default for all the elements.

```
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
ul.addEventListener('click', e => {
const li = e.target.matches('.className');

if(!li) return

ListItems.forEach(li => li.style.width = 'YourValue');
li.style.left = YourValue;
})
```